# Как вывести данные из базы в формате JSON (с помощью php)?

Tags: php, sql, json, fullcalendar

Доброго времени суток всем.
Есть 3 таблицы:

1. bio_vet_calendar

   ```
   1) id
   2) doctorid (ID доктора)
   3) clinicid (ID клиники)
   4) start (тут время)
   5) end (тут время)
   ```
2. bio_vet_clinic_department

   ```
   1) clinicid (ID клиники)
   2) clinic-name (Название клиники)
   ```
3. bio_vet_doctor

   ```
   1) doctorid (ID доктора)
   2) doctor-name (ФИО доктора)
   ```

Нужно получить вот такой json

```
{
   doctorid: '1', - ID доктора
   doctor-name: '1', - Имя доктора
   clinicid: '1', - ID клиники
   clinic-name: '1', - Название клиники
   start: '2019-06-01'
   end: '2019-06-02'
},
{
   doctorid: '2', - ID доктора
   doctor-name: '2', - Имя доктора
   clinicid: '2', - ID клиники
   clinic-name: '2', - Название клиники
   start: '2019-06-03'
   end: '2019-06-04'
},
{
   doctorid: '3', - ID доктора
   doctor-name: '3', - Имя доктора
   clinicid: '3', - ID клиники
   clinic-name: '3', - Название клиники
   start: '2019-06-05'
   end: '2019-06-06'
}
```

Думаю получать данные только связанные с доктором на странице доктора через

```
SELECT * 
FROM bio_vet_doctor 
where doctorid=1
```

Помогите кто чем может.

Comment: $object = json_decode(json_encode($array));

Comment: У меня сейчас подключение к базе реализовано вот таким способом:
$query = "SELECT * FROM bio_vet_calendar where doctorid=$doctorid";
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM bio_vet_clinic_department";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM bio_vet_doctor where doctorid=$doctorid";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error());
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1) or die('Query failed1: ' . mysqli_error());
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die('Query failed2: ' . mysqli_error());

Comment: СУБД укажите, включая версию. PS. Поскольку сейчас практически все СУБД знают про JSON, ляпать его из сырого набора данных на стороне PHP - глупость.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4SRqAS7J8U&t=44s

Answer (score 0):

Запрос к базе

```
SELECT `doctorid`,`doctor-name`,`clinicid`,`clinic-name`,`start`,`end`
FROM `bio_vet_doctor`
LEFT JOIN `bio_vet_calendar` USING `doctorid`
LEFT JOIN `bio_vet_clinic_department` USING `clinicid`
```

Перевести ответ от БД в json

```
$json = json_encode( array );
```